How to enable original audio in Zoom app?
Most Zoom apps support an "original audio" setting that disables noise filtering. This is very helpful if you want to play music or get music lessons over Zoom, because otherwise zoom filters out the music.
I see this option in the Windows, Linux, and Mac clients, but for the life of me I can't find it in the android client. I'm using a Galaxy Tab S8, and I've ensured the app is up to date.
In the linux client, this option is located under the More menu. Several online guides also say that it should be located under the manage settings menu. However, no such options exist for me in either location.




The official Zoom support docs say it should be available.
Is this option simply not supported on android? If it is then where can find it?
